# Can't manipulate TextView for a custom dialog

Tags: android, textview

This will throw a null pointer exception and crash the app. Can't figure out why. It might be because of some funky thread business. I'm thinking maybe a handler might fix it. I'll give that a try in the meantime if anyone has any ideas I'm all ears. Thanks

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
06-04 15:42:34.644: W/dalvikvm(6535): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dca438)
```

Code that propagates the error:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// Get the layout inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null));

Log.i(TAG, "Getting TextView and appending");

((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName)).append("appended string");

builder.create().show();
```

Comment: have you tried it as `((TextView) Your_Current_Activity.this.findViewById(R.id.tvName)).setText("whatever");` ?

Comment: I gave it a try, still same error. I think its got to be a thread issue. I keep getting a warning saying thread exiting with uncaught exception. What is a good way to correct this?

Comment: plz show more code and full log which you are getting when app is creating

Comment: Where is R.id.tvName defined? Is it a view or subview of a view returned in `getInfoWindow` or `getInfoContents`?

Comment: tvName is a textview object declared in a linear layout xml file used to create a dialog.

Comment: Put the code that creates this dialog.

Comment: See my revisions. I am changing the TextView object that goes inside the custom layout of a dialog incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

builder.setView(view);

Log.i(TAG, "Getting TextView and appending");

((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)).append("appended string");

builder.create().show();
```

if `R.id.tvName` belongs to `R.layout.my_layout` you have to use the inflated view to retrieve it

Comment: Makes sense it should come off the inflated view from which it originates. Thank you much